# How to save (and retrieve) to file a sequence of bits

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, ostream, istream

I'm trying to store in a file a sequence of bits.

I try to describe only the essential:

- I have a vector (I know, not a good idea, but I only use it briefly)
- I want to store it in a file (I'm using Linux)
- I want to retrieve it from said file and recreate the vector

Since C++ doesn't allow the storing of single bits, I had to group all the bits in char and save the char as a "text".
To do so I used this http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/tut-c-bit-manipulation-aka-programming-101

If the number of bits is multiple of 8, everything works fine.
If this is not the case, I don't know how to handle the problem.

I'll explain better. I have:

```
010011000110111101110010011001010110110101
```

I save the chars as:

```
01001100 -> L
01101111 -> o
01110010 -> r
01100101 -> e
01101101 -> m
01
```

That last "01"... I don't know how to store it.
Of course I could create a byte with a 1 and some 0 padding... but I don't know the number of "extra bits" when I retrieve them!
What is padding and what is info?

I simply don't know how to do this... any idea?

Some code for the file writer (Not my actual code... its too long... I wrote only the important parts...):

```
void Compressor::compress(std::istream &is, std::ostream &os) {
  queue<bool> bit_buffer;
  char c;

  while (is.get(c)) {
      new_letter = c;
      const std::vector<bool> bit_c = char2bits(new_letter);
      for(bool bit : bit_c) 
        bit_buffer.push(bit);
  }
  //Here my code adds a certain number of bits, I simulate this with:
  bit_buffer.push(false);
  bit_buffer.push(true);

  // Write the bit buffer into a file
  while (bit_buffer.size() >= 8) {

    // Group vector<bool> in char
    char output = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
      int bit = bit_buffer.front();
      bit_buffer.pop();
      if (bit) bit_set(output, BIT(i));
      else bit_clear(output, BIT(i));
    }

    // Individually write chars in file
    os.write(&output,sizeof(char));
  }

  //????????
  //Last bits???
  //????????
}

vector<bool> char2bits (char c) {
  bitset<8> bit_c (c);
  vector<bool> bool_c;
  for (int i=7; i>=0; i--) {
    bool_c.push_back(bit_c[i]);
  }
  return bool_c;
}
```

Comment: One option would be to store a header in the file indicating the number of bits that are expected to follow. You can then use this to determine how many bits to read (and detect errors if the file isn't as long as you expect). This would take the form of just an integer that you write before any of the packed bit data. Just make sure the integer is wide enough to hold the largest file length that you can ever expect to use.

Comment: I thought about the header idea. Since my problem is when I have from 1 to 7 spare bits, I can use 3 bits in front of the stream to indicate the exact number. The problem here is that I am trying to compress a lot of stuff and a padded byte plus these 3 bits are a lot of space wasted... I will use this as my last resource!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do bit padding is to pad with `10...0`.

So `01` gets padded to `01100000`.

When decoding, just ignore everything behind the last `1`.

If you have a full byte in the end, pad with `10000000`.

Comment: Nice idea! I'll try this!

Answer (score 0):

I would use header too, but for a group of payload bytes.
I mean :

```
HH PP PP PP PP PP PP ..
HH PP PP
```

- If **HH == 256**, ok, you've got 32 bits of Payload and then you'll find
  another chunk
- If **HH < 256**, you've have to read next *int(HH/8)* bytes and within the last one, *HH % 8* bits. In addition, it's meaning the file is over.

For large bit fields, you may increase the header to 16 or 32 bits.

Comment: This is a very interesting idea, but I am trying to absolutely avoid every kind of overhead. Its a compressor after all... I can't use whole bytes just to handle the last 1.